# What does the Linux kernel function dm_per_bio_data do?

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, memory-alignment

I am trying to understand the code for a kernel module that makes some function calls from the kernel source. The code is in [device-mapper.h](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/device-mapper.h).

```
struct dm_target_io {
    struct dm_io *io;
    struct dm_target *ti;
    unsigned target_bio_nr;
    unsigned *len_ptr;
    struct bio clone;
};

static inline void *dm_per_bio_data(struct bio *bio, size_t data_size)
{
    return (char *)bio - offsetof(struct dm_target_io, clone) - data_size;
}
```

We are told elsewhere, in a comment in device_mapper.h, that "dm_per_bio_data returns the data location." I am not sure why this is the case.

First, dm_per_bio_data takes a struct bio* and subtracts it by offsetof(struct dm_target_io, clone), which should give the start of the enclosing dm_target_io struct. Then, it subtracts data_size, which takes the pointer to--where?

I've been looking to see where dm_target_io is declared inside another struct to see where subtracting by data_size might take me. No such luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`per_io_data_size` is the key here. By setting the member of `struct dm_target`, device-mapper allocates the extra space for user-defined data ahead of dm_target_io so they are placed like this:

(extra)(dm_target_io  ...   (clone))

so dm_per_bio_data returns the pointer to the beginning of the extra space.

```
struct dm_md_mempools *dm_alloc_md_mempools(struct mapped_device *md, enum dm_queue_mode type,
                                            unsigned integrity, unsigned per_io_data_size)
{
        struct dm_md_mempools *pools = kzalloc_node(sizeof(*pools), GFP_KERNEL, md->numa_node_id);
        unsigned int pool_size = 0;
        unsigned int front_pad;

        if (!pools)
                return NULL;

        switch (type) {
        case DM_TYPE_BIO_BASED:
        case DM_TYPE_DAX_BIO_BASED:
                pool_size = dm_get_reserved_bio_based_ios();
                front_pad = roundup(per_io_data_size, __alignof__(struct dm_target_io)) + offsetof(struct dm_target_io, clone);

                pools->io_pool = mempool_create_slab_pool(pool_size, _io_cache);
                if (!pools->io_pool)
                        goto out;
                break;
        case DM_TYPE_REQUEST_BASED:
        case DM_TYPE_MQ_REQUEST_BASED:
                pool_size = dm_get_reserved_rq_based_ios();
                front_pad = offsetof(struct dm_rq_clone_bio_info, clone);
                /* per_io_data_size is used for blk-mq pdu at queue allocation */
                break;
        default:
                BUG();
        }

        pools->bs = bioset_create(pool_size, front_pad, BIOSET_NEED_RESCUER);
        if (!pools->bs)
                goto out;
```